# reloading data/refreshing data in parent ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, viewwillappear, popviewcontroller

From a parent VC two other VCs get pushed (first adds a group, second adds some (optional) more data); after popping them the parent VC appears but the new data (new group) is not added. I am using `UIRefreshControl` to pull to refresh calling `loadGroups(toRefresh: true)` with a `Bool` value indicating if refreshing data is needed.
I would like to call same method automatically when closing the pushed VCs, so after parent VC reappears it presents new data w/o the need for pulling to refresh. I tried doing so in `viewWillAppear` but then the method gets called twice- first when the parent VC first appears and then after popping the overlaying controllers. Is there a method to make sure it gets called only once (when-reappearing)?

Comment: A *swifty* way is a callback closure.

Comment: thanks, where would the closure be called?

Comment: In the child view controller.

Comment: Another way is to setup NSNotifcaition and send between controllers

Comment: @iphonic Don't use `Notification` if the controllers are related to each other.

Comment: Delegate or Closure if "they know each others" (usually, one "owns“ the other, or are on the "same level"). Notification if they are far away from each other. In your case, it's a parent => Closure/Delegate.